# 2 elements with same CSS, modify the first one only

Tags: css

```
<header class="entry-header">
   <div class="entry-header-inner">
       <h1 class="entry-title">TITLE 1</h1>
   </div>
</header>
```

elsewhere on the page:

```
<header class="entry-header">
   <div class="entry-header-inner">
       <h2 class="entry-title">TITLE 2</h2>
   </div>
</header>
```

I want to affect TITLE 1 with css, without affecting TITLE 2.
This is a generated code, I can't add ID. Also I didn't find suitable parent for TITLE 1.

How should I do it? Possibly without javascript or Jquery. With it if not possible.

Comment: No, without adding specificity this is not possible. There is no `nth-of-class`. So you need to be able to select *this* element by reference to other ancestors...or use javascript to select it by the inner text content.

Comment: You can try `header:nth-child(1) h1{ ... }` if title 1 is inside the first header in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply some CSS on `.entry-title h1` which will only be applied for TITLE 1 since your TITLE 2 is an `h2`

-**EDIT:**: Use `.entry-header-inner h1` not `.entry-title h1`

Comment: this approach works, but targeting a level higher with .entry-header-inner h1. If you modify your answer I will select it as solution.

Comment: Oops yes my mistake didn't took the right class, I've edited my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select the title of first header, whatsoever it is `H1` or `H2`, the following code should work.

```
.entry-header:nth-child(1) .entry-title{ /* your css here */ }
```